# how to install whatsapp?

Tags: software-installation

[image]

The picture is the screenshot and you could see the error message. It cannot be copied and so I took screenshot.

any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Download an install chrome

[image]

Then go to [Chrome WebStore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions?hl=en-US&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher) and look for `Messenger for WhatsApp` and install it. Now go to the `Apps` section in Chrome, right click on `Messenger for WhatsApp` -> `Create shortcuts` -> tick Applications menu -> Close. Start WhatsApp from Applications and pair it using the QR code.  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try Rambox...it's a multi chat app and whatsapp is also included
http://rambox.pro/

Answer (score 0):

After an unsuccessful install of something by a missing dependency using `apt` one could use `sudo apt install -f` to satisfy all dependency packages needed in order to install other packages.

`sudo apt install <some_package>`

Dependency not satisfied in the last operation so:

`sudo apt install -f`

Now the dependencies are satisfied and the package `<some_package>` is installed properly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's still under development but a year (or two) back I came across an unofficial WhatsApp client called **Whatsie**. I found it to be very useful. You should definitely check it out.